# Webhooks in Microsoft Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Is there a limit to notifications?

For example, if I move 30 messages to another folder, I get 30 notification with a `clientState` of `update`. If I move more than 30 messages, I'm not getting any notifications.

How many updates can I make per second to get all notification?